# Protractor not stopping on .pause() method

Tags: protractor

Protractor gurus!

I have the following issue: the browser.pause(); method seems not to work. At all.
I read before that it has some issues with later versions of Node, but still. Do any of you can help / give suggestions how to overcome this? I just need the browser to pause at that line.

Here is my code:

```
var disbursment=require('./pages/disbursment.js')
    it('fill disbursment fields', function(){
      disbursment.disbursmentTab();
      disbursment.disbursmentDate('12/12/12');
      disbursment.disburser('test');
      disbursment.disburserNotes('notes here');
      disbursment.disbursetAmount('3400');
      disbursment.isInvoiceValid();
      browser.pause();
      disbursment.centerlinkPayment();
      disbursment.clientNotified();
```

Protractor Version: 5.4.2

​Node version: 10.16.3

Comment: for what purpose? You can just add `browser.sleep(100000000000.....)` and it will be the same)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment! Well... not quite the same, actually. .sleep(...) will "freeze" the browser waiting, while .pause() is supposed to stop and "debug" via some commands in the console. I would like to be able to pause the browser and use the console.

Comment: I spent a while figuring out how that `.pause()` supposed to work and luckily I couldn't. This made me switch to the use of webstorm's debugging configuration and I tell you it worth spending time, since it doesn't require changing your code (adding `browser.pause()`), and still can debug (explore your variables and elements)

Comment: I really would like to use Protractor, all my automated tests are written on it. But still - I cannot pause the browser.